# How to access ethernet ports from both RPU and APU?

Tags: embedded-linux, xilinx, freertos, vitis-ai, zynq-ultrascale+

​

I am using ZU19EG Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC bought from iWave with APU – Cortex 53 (quadcore) and RPU – Cortex R5 (dualcore). On this board, I am trying to run the sample lwIP echo server application provided in Vitis 2021.1 on RPU in lockstep mode and Linux on APU. When I power on the board, the RPU application starts fine and I am able to see UDP messages on host PC. But, while Linux boots on APU, the connection to RPU is lost and I am unable to ping RPU any more. But, I continue to see that the application is running fine on RPU from the messages over UART. I would like to know how to fix this issue of losing connection to RPU from host while Linux boots on APU.

Here are the detailed steps on how I am booting the board:

First I am building the image using petalinux (Attaching patch and xsa files):

- source ~/petalinux/settings.sh
- petalinux-create --type project --template zynqMP --name zynqmp-iwg35m
- cd zynqmp-iwg35m/
- patch -Np1 < ../PATCH000-iW-PRGBZ-SC-01-R1.5-REL1.0-ED3.0-PL21.1_customization.patch
- petalinux-config --get-hw-description=/home/docs/19EG-1I-R15-ED30-21_1-F1_0/system.xsa
- petalinux-build
- petalinux-package --boot --format BIN --fsbl images/linux/zynqmp_fsbl.elf --pmufw images/linux/pmufw.elf --atf images/linux/bl31.elf --fpga images/linux/system.bit --u-boot images/linux/u-boot.elf -o images/linux/BOOT.bin

Generate Platform Project from xsa:

- In the Vitis IDE, go to File → New → Platform Project.
- In the Create New Platform page, enter the 'platform_name' and click Next.
- In the Platform view, go with the default tab Create from hardware specification (XSA).
- Click Browse… to select the XSA file.
- In the platform window select Operating system as 'standalone', Processor as 'psu_cortexa53_0' and Target processor to create FSBL as 'psu_cortexa53_0' and click on Finish.
- Build the platform project.

Create lwIP application for R5:

- In Vitis, File -> New -> Application Project
- Next
- Give application name, select psu_cortexr5_0 -> next
- Choose operating system as standalone -> next
- Select lwIP Echo Server template -> finish
- In src/ldscript.ld change psu_r5ddr_0_MEM_0 Base Address: 0x70000000 and Size: 0x10000000
- Replace xemacpsif_physpeed.c with the file from BareMetal FTP attached here
- Save and build

Create Linux Domain:

- Open platform.spr -> click on “+”
- Name: Linux_Domain
- Display Name: Linux_Domain
- OS: Linux
- Processor: psu_cortexa53
- Supported Runtimes: C/C++
- Architecture: 64-bit
- Bif File: vitis_ws\zu19eg\export\zu19eg\sw\zu19eg\boot\zu19eg.bif
- Boot Component Directory: The linux/images directory that you created in petalinux step
- FAT32 Partition Directory: The linux/images directory that you created in petalinux step
- OK
- Build the platform project

Create Linux application:

- In Vitis, File -> New -> Application Project
- Next
- Give application name, select psu_cortexa53_0 -> next
- Choose operating system as Linux (should be set automatically) -> next
- Select Hello world template -> finish
- Build the project

Finally, generate boot image:

- Xilinx -> create boot image -> zynq and zynqMP UltraScale
- Create new bif file
- arch: ZynqMP
- select bif output path
- Add FSBL (under zu19eg/export/sw/……/Linux_domain/images/zynqmp_fsbl.elf) -> ok (default values)
- Add pmufw.elf from same path as above -> pmu(loaded by bootrom) -> ok
- Add system.bit from same path -> default values -> ok
- bl31.elf -> enable trust zone -> ok
- add R5 lwip application elf -> R5 lockstep -> ok
- add u-boot.elf from same path as other files before R5 app -> Exception: EL2 -> ok
- create Image

Copy Contents to SD card:

- Copy: BOOT.bin, image.ub to SD card and set board to SD boot -> connect ethernet to first port beside UART and to PC.
- On PC set IP: 192.168.1.1, mask 255.255.255.0, default gateway: 192.168.1.10
- Open serial terminal -> both boot from APU and app messages from RPU printed here (in current config )
- Open wireshark -> All I see is ARP and no response from board
- Tried ping 192.168.1.10 But, destination is unreachable.

Please let me know if you need any further details from my end that could help you in providing required support.

​

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: I am not sure how to attach files here. Let me know if you need them.